# Topic Modelling mallet: how to interpret the Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: java, mallet

After obtaining various probability distributions from various documents in mallet, I have applied the following code to calculate the KL divergence between the first and the second document:

```
        Maths.klDivergence(double[] d1,double[] d2);
```

How should I interpret the data obtained? For example, I get: 12.3640...
What does this mean? the two distributions are near or far away?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, KL-Divergence gives the divergence of one distribution from another. it is basically the information a distribution loses while approximating to another distribution which means - Lesser the value, more the similarity. If more similar you don't lose any information